# How does SparkSQL create Jobs/Stages

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am looking into Spark's implementation. I know in Spark core, when calling an action on a RDD, `sc.runJob` will finally be called, which will submit job to `DAGScheduler`.

I want to know how `DAGSheculer` schedules Spark SQL Jobs, so I trace a call to an action on a Dataset. I find it calls `sparkplan.executeCollect()`, which will finally call `doExecute()` depend on which specific `SparkPlan` it is.

However when I look into [objects.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/objects.scala), I find no `sc.runJob` call, but lots `child.execute()`. I don't know where it ends.

My question is where does a Dataset action create a Job.